# Data on redux store return to initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, I store *navigate* on redux store when the app start:

```
//in App.js file
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom' 

const App = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(addNavigate(navigate))
   }, [dispatch, navigate]); 
}
```

And when I use useSelector to select navigate in redux store in another component, it returns **undefined**. How can I fix it (if I am not use useNavigate directly in this component) and why navigate object became initial state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Redux Docs:

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.

> If you are okay with things like persistence and time-travel debugging potentially not working as intended, then you are totally welcome to put non-serializable items into your Redux store. Ultimately, it's your application, and how you implement it is up to you. As with many other things about Redux, just be sure you understand what tradeoffs are involved.

With all that said, if you still want to add the `navigate` function from the `useNavigate` hook you would only be able to get a valid defined value for `navigate` if it is called in a child component of `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

So in the top level component this wouldn't work, instead we'd need something like this for your `App.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import createStore from './createReduxStore'

const store = createStore()

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Content />
    </Provider
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Then in your `Content` component you can do what you initially intended:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom' 

const Content = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(addNavigate(navigate))
   }, [navigate]); 
}
```